# how to store function value in variable and display it on textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to store value of function in the variable and want to display the content in text area `t1`.

So every time I push the value I can get the print function in the variable `s` and can display content in textarea `t1`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stack With Constructor </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Stack </div>
        <div>
            <h1>stack</h1>
            <h2>Stage1.</h2>
            <p id="p1">
                stack
            </p>
            <textarea id="t1"></textarea>
            <button onclick="doJob()">push</button>
            <button onclick="doJob1()">pop</button>
        </div>
        <textarea id="t"></textarea>
        <script>
            function push(v) {
                if (this.st === 0) {
                    console.log("Stack Overflow");
                } else {
                    this.st = this.st - 1;
                    this.stk[this.st] = v;
                }
            }

            function pop() {
                if (this.st === 10) {
                    console.log("Stack Underflow");
                } else {
                    var temp = this.stk[this.st];
                    this.st = this.st + 1;
                    return temp;
                }
            }

            function print() {
                console.log("Printing Stack");
                for (var i = this.st ; i < 10; i++) {
                    console.log(this.stk[i]);
                }
            };

            function MyStack() {
                this.st = 10;
                this.stk = new Array(10);
                this.push = push;
                this.pop = pop;
                this.print = print;
            };

            var s1 = new MyStack();

            function doJob() {
                var x=document.getElementById("t").value;
                s1.push(x);
                var s=s1.print();
                document.getElementById("t1").value=s;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to display the print function in the text area `t1` so it can work as interactive stack.

When I try to push value, I am getting `undefined` in the textarea.

Comment: do you want the print function's body?

Comment: Please define "the value of a functon". Something you want to return from `s1.print`? Notice, that `print` in the global scope overrides the native `window.print` method.

Comment: i would like to print content of print in the text area

Comment: `var s=s1.print;`..? Or the same text as `print` logs to the console?

Comment: var s can get the print output and can display on textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your print function like,

```
        function print() {
            console.log("Printing Stack");
            var str = "";//empty string
            for (var i = this.st ; i < 10; i++) {
                console.log(this.stk[i]);
                str+=this.stk[i]+'\n';//concatenate the value and a new line
            }
            return str;
        };
```

**DEMO**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stack With Constructor </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Stack </div>
        <div>
            <h1>stack</h1>
            <h2>Stage1.</h2>
            <p id="p1">
                stack
            </p>
            <textarea id="t1"></textarea>
            <button onclick="doJob()">push</button>
            <button onclick="doJob1()">pop</button>
        </div>
        <textarea id="t"></textarea>
        <script>
            function push(v) {
                if (this.st === 0) {
                    console.log("Stack Overflow");
                } else {
                    this.st = this.st - 1;
                    this.stk[this.st] = v;
                }
            }

            function pop() {
                if (this.st === 10) {
                    console.log("Stack Underflow");
                } else {
                    var temp = this.stk[this.st];
                    this.st = this.st + 1;
                    return temp;
                }
            }

            function print() {
                console.log("Printing Stack");
                var str = "";//empty string
                for (var i = this.st ; i < 10; i++) {
                    console.log(this.stk[i]);
                    str+=this.stk[i]+'\n';//concatenate the value and a new line
                }
                return str;
            };

            function MyStack() {
                this.st = 10;
                this.stk = new Array(10);
                this.push = push;
                this.pop = pop;
                this.print = print;
            };

            var s1 = new MyStack();

            function doJob() {
                var x=document.getElementById("t").value;
                s1.push(x);
                var s=s1.print();
                document.getElementById("t1").value=s;
            }
            function doJob1(){
                s1.pop();
                var s=s1.print();
                document.getElementById("t1").value=s;                
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: when i try to pop it is not displaying on the text area.

Comment: You will have to call the print function again just like you did in push.

Comment: i called print function in pop but not working.function doJob1(){
                  var y=s1.pop();
                  document.getElementById("tpop").value=y;
                  document.getElementById("tdisplay").value=s1.print();

Comment: Did you check your console, are you getting some error?

Comment: yeah i see. Trying to figure out.

Comment: thanks a lot.i do have one question how i can make it interactive using checkbox?i mean i can select two checkbox s1 and s2 and can work on different stacks according to my need.

Comment: i updated question for that please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660858/interactive-stack-using-checkbox-s1-and-s2-and-different-functions